# Can't save features of drawn Circle to JSON in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers-3

So, here's the thing: I want to draw a circle on my map in OL3 and then save it to a JSON file. As I understood you can't write circular geometry to JSON (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3552). I used the OL3 example to draw shapes and changed it to use ol.geom.Polygon.circular method to avoid using circle geometry. When I try to save it I get "TypeError: cyclic object value".

```
if (value) {
var geometryFunction, maxPoints;
    if (value === 'Circle') {
        value='Circle';
        maxPoints=2;
        geometryFunction = function (coordinates, geometry) {
        if (!geometry) {
        geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
                    }
      var center = coordinates[0];
      var last = coordinates[1];
      var dx = center[0] - last[0];
      var dy = center[1] - last[1];
      var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      geometry = ol.geom.Polygon.circular(wgs84Sphere, center, radius);
      return geometry;
                }; 
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features:features,
                type: value,
                geometryFunction: geometryFunction,
                maxPoints: maxPoints
            });
            map.addInteraction(draw);
```

That's how I save JSON:

```
var writer = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var geojsonStr = writer.writeFeatures(source.getFeatures());
alert(geojsonStr);
```

I'm pretty sure there must be a way to draw and save circles to JSON using ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle or ol.geom.Polygon.circular. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you store any complex properties (i.e. other than strings or numbers) on your features, e.g. using `feature.set()`? Hard to guess what's going on without seeing your application live.

Comment: This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/px6ks0am/
Because JSON can't get circular geometry, the written features are empty. How can I avoid using the circle at all or transform it to polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a custom `geometryFunction`, you must use the existing `geometry` that is passed as 2nd argument to the geometry function, if it is available. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/px6ks0am/1/.

The key to success is the following `geometryFunction`, which also takes care of reprojecting the circular polygon properly:

```
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
function geometryFunction(coordinates, geometry) {
  if (!geometry) {
    geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
  }
  var center = coordinates[0];
  var last = coordinates[1];
  var dx = center[0] - last[0];
  var dy = center[1] - last[1];
  var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  var circle = ol.geom.Polygon.circular(wgs84Sphere, ol.proj.toLonLat(center), radius);
  circle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  geometry.setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
  return geometry;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a valueable answer! I could find some some examples of esage of ol.geom.Polygon.circular, but none of them dealt with the actual drawing. Appreciate it!